# Kafka Producer/Consumer crushing every second API call

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

Everytime I make the second API call, I get an error in Postman saying "There was an internal server error."
I don't understand if the problem is related to my kafka producer or consumer, they both worked just fine yesterday. The messages don't arrive anymore to the consumer and I can't make a second API call as the code crushes every second time (without giving any logs in Scala)
This is my producer code:

```
    class Producer(topic: String, brokers: String) {
    
      val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](configuration)
    
      private def configuration: Properties = {
        val props = new Properties()
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers)
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all")
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringSerializer].getCanonicalName)
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringSerializer].getCanonicalName)
        props
      }
    
      def sendMessages(message: String): Unit = {
        val record = new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, "1", message)
        producer.send(record)
        producer.close()
      }
    
    }
```

This is where I'm using it:

```
    object Message extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport {
    
      val newConversation = new Producer(brokers = KAFKA_BROKER, topic = "topic_2")
    
      def sendMessage(sender_id: String, receiver_id: String, content: String): String = {
        val JsonMessage = Map("sender_id" -> sender_id, "receiver_id" -> receiver_id, "content" -> content)
        val i = JsonMessage.toJson.prettyPrint
        newConversation.sendMessages(i)
        "Message Sent"
      }
    }
```

And this is the API:

```
f

    inal case class Message(sender_id: String, receiver_id: String, content: String)
    
    object producerRoute extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport {
      implicit val MessageFormat = jsonFormat3(Message)
    
      val sendMessageRoute:Route = (post & path("send")){
        entity(as[Message]){
          msg => {
            complete(sendMessage(msg.sender_id,msg.receiver_id,msg.content))
          }
          }
      }
    }
```

On the other hand, this is my Consumer code:

```
    class Consumer(brokers: String, topic: String, groupId: String) {
    
      val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](configuration)
      consumer.subscribe(util.Arrays.asList(topic))
    
      private def configuration: Properties = {
        val props = new Properties()
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers)
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringDeserializer].getCanonicalName)
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringDeserializer].getCanonicalName)
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId)
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true)
        props
      }
    
      def receiveMessages():Array[String]  = {
      val a:ArrayBuffer[String] = new ArrayBuffer[String]
        while (true) {
          val records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(0))
          records.forEach(record => a.addOne(record.value()))
        }
        println(a.toArray)
        a.toArray
      }
    }
    
    object Consumer extends App {
    
      val consumer = new Consumer(brokers = KAFKA_BROKER, topic = "topic_2", groupId = "test")
      consumer.receiveMessages()
    }
```

I don't even get the result from the print in the consumer anymore. I don't understand what's the problem as it worked just fine before and I didn't change anything since the last time it worked.

Comment: You are closing the producer after sending a message, so, yeah ... I don't see how you could ever send more than one.

Comment: Won't there be problems if I never close the producer ?

Comment: No. KafkaProducer instances are thread safe. You should only ever create one and not close until the app stops

Comment: "don't even get the result from the print in the consumer anymore" - Did you try using a different groupId? Do you understand what `ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true` is doing?

Comment: Well, _never_ closing might be a problem. Not closing before you are done using it is a different story (definitely a good idea).

Comment: @OneCricketeer what does ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true has to do with the consumer printing out or not?

Comment: For example, you have no active producer. You fully consume the topic, and data does get printed. Then, the consumer group offset automatically gets committed. Next time you run the consumer, it'll pickup from the last committed offset (the end of the topic). Since there's no producer, there's no new offsets to consume, so nothing gets printed... Similarly, on a brand new consumer group, `auto.offset.reset=latest` is used, and there's no data to print at the end of the topic; did you mean to use `auto.offset.reset=earliest`?

Comment: Well, yeah that's exactly the point, unless there's a NEW message to consume, don't consume anything, I guess